# Javascript how to put variable in a URICOMPONENT

Tags: javascript

```
var frank_param = gup( 'frank' );
var pageURL = encodeURIComponent("directory_doctor_page.php?DoctorID=23");
```

I have those two lines of code I want to replace the 23 with the var frank.
How will I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: what does the gup() function do?

Comment: gup() grabs a url parameter from http://example.com/index.php?frank=23. It grabs the #23 out of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate both like this:

```
var pageURL = encodeURIComponent("directory_doctor_page.php?DoctorID=" + frank_param);
```

Extract from mozilla's JS documentation on [String operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators):

> In addition to the comparison operators, which can be used on string
>   values, the concatenation operator (+) concatenates two string values
>   together, returning another string that is the union of the two
>   operand strings. For example, "my " + "string" returns the string "my
>   string".
>
> The shorthand assignment operator += can also be used to concatenate
>   strings. For example, if the variable mystring has the value "alpha",
>   then the expression mystring += "bet" evaluates to "alphabet" and
>   assigns this value to mystring.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate the variable to the string:

```
var frank_param = gup( 'frank' );
var pageURL = encodeURIComponent("directory_doctor_page.php?DoctorID=" + frank_param );
```

I'd suggest taking a look at some [JavaScript Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info#h-related-tags), on the StackOverflow FAQ.